retention.ms not respected for a specific kafka topic
We are running strimzi with kafka in a openshift cluster.
We have multiple topics, all with the same retention.ms settings: 259200000 which is 72 hours.
We observed that kafka disk space have been decreasing over time.
To check where the space is used, we exec'ed into one of the kafka pods, and ran:
du -sh /var/lib/kafka/data/kafka-log0/* | sort -hr
This produced the following output
bash-4.4$ du -sh /var/lib/kafka/data/kafka-log0/* | sort -hr
149G    /var/lib/kafka/data/kafka-log0/mytopic1-0
29G     /var/lib/kafka/data/kafka-log0/mytopic2-0
3.6G    /var/lib/kafka/data/kafka-log0/mytopic3-0
681M    /var/lib/kafka/data/kafka-log0/mytopic4-security-0

Checking the /var/lib/kafka/data/kafka-log0/mytopic1-0 revealed that there is data as far back as 28th of march, which is over a month old data.
This with a retention set to 72 hours.
total 155550304
-rw-rw-r--. 1 1000760000 1000760000       6328 Mar 28 10:17 00000000001211051718.index
-rw-rw-r--. 1 1000760000 1000760000   12339043 Mar 28 10:17 00000000001211051718.log
-rw-rw-r--. 1 1000760000 1000760000       1164 Mar 28 10:17 00000000001211051718.timeindex

For the other topics that has the same retention settings, the data in i the folders is in line with the retention settings.
Having checked the oldest file earlier this morning, no change has been made in the old files. So it seems to removal of old files is not taking place for this specific topic.
Kubernetes: OpenShift
Kafka image: kafka:0.35.1-kafka-3.4.0
Kafka version: 3.4.0
Strimzi version: 0.35.1

KafkaTopic - the one that has the issue
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaTopic
metadata:
  annotations:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: kafka
    strimzi.io/cluster: kafka
  name: mytopic1
  namespace: kafka-ns
  resourceVersion: "162114882"
  uid: 266caad6-c73d-4a23-9913-6c9a64f505ca
spec:
  config:
    retention.ms: 259200000
    segment.bytes: 1073741824
  partitions: 1
  replicas: 3
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2023-10-27T09:03:58.698836682Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  observedGeneration: 2
  topicName: mytopic1

Another kafka topic without issues
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaTopic
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: kafka
    strimzi.io/cluster: kafka
  name: mytopic2
  namespace: kafka-ns
  resourceVersion: "162114874"
  uid: 871b5fab-7996-4674-a0b4-d3476cbe9c6c
spec:
  config:
    retention.ms: 259200000
    segment.bytes: 1073741824
  partitions: 1
  replicas: 3
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2023-10-27T09:03:58.539808920Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  observedGeneration: 2
  topicName: mytopic2

Any ideas on where to check to try to get to the root cause?

The reason for this was that the clients sending messages had an incorrect timestamp, set in the future, 2024-12-06.
Kafka used this client timestamp as the timestamp for all messages, and thus the retention period of 3 days would start 3 days after 2024-12-06.
We added retention.bytes as well as a mitigation until the people managing the client can address the issue.
